# Getting attributes bonuses +5/+5/+5 in Elder scrolls oblivion

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

I have just completed the recommended quests for the Mages Guild to get accepted into the Arcane University. Now, I think it's time to work on leveling up the mage class character that I have. I'm currently on Level 1 and I want increase the Intelligence, Willpower, and Endurance or Personality of my character by +5 for each level up. For this I have created some custom spells for +1 duration and casting them repeatedly to gain required skills such as:

- For Alteration skill whose affected attribute is *Willpower*, I have a custom Shield spell.
- For Conjuration skill whose affected attribute is *Intelligence*, I have a custom Summon Skeleton spell.
- For Illusion skill whose affected attribute is *Personality*, I have a custom Light
  spell.

So, now If I want to get +5/+5/+5 bonus for three attributes Willpower, Intelligence, and Personality. How many times do I need cast and in what way do I need to work my way to level up?

Answer (score 2):

The default leveling system of oblivion is pretty complicated, well at least to get those 5x every time on 3 different attributes. What you need to do to get a 5X on a specific attribute is leveling a corresponding skills 10 times. So if you want to level strength you can level the blade skill 10 times, 4 levels blade and 6 levels blunt or any combination of strength skills.

The problem is if you level 10 major skills you will level up so you have to pick the skills carefully when you create your characters. With carefully i also mean unlogically, since if you want to build i fighter and have block and heavy armor (both endurance skills) you can only get +5 to endurance if you level only those major skills, or mix in some armorer (also a endurance skill). So if you level block 3 times, heavy armor 3 times and another major skill like blade 4 times you will not get 5X to endurance unless you leveled armorer 4 times as well that level.

Since you are able to pick 3 5X each level up things get weird and complicated. What i usually did is pick a skill for every attribute and make it the least favorable skill for your character so you have more control on when you will level up. Since if you would pick light armor as a major and wearing light armor at the same time that skill would level up very fast and you will have to get rid of the armor or you will risk a level up without 5X picks.

In your case, if you would pick Alteration, conjuration and illusion as a major skill you could get 5x to all corresponding attributes like this:

- level mercantile/speechcraft 7 levels.
- level Alchemy/mysticism 7
- levels. level Destruction/restoration 6 levels.

You need to do all the above before you level up.

- Level illusion 3 levels.
- Level Conjuration 3 levels.
- Level Alteration 4 levels.

Only this way, or at least with combinations like this would get you 5X at all 3 attributes.

This however is called power leveling and will make you very strong later in the game so you do not need to play like this. In my honest opinion it wastes all the immersion of the game since you need to be constantly counting your levels.

However, there are mods that count this for you. There are also mods that modify the leveling system which i personally prefer. I used the "[AF level mod](http://oblivion.nexusmods.com/mods/3244/?)" very often, it raises your attributes at the same time as you level the corresponding skills. You do not have to sleep either. You can just play the game without ever worrying about getting those 5X modifiers.

Comment: Yeah, the leveling mods are all much, much better than the vanilla leveling system.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Vanilla oblivion is a average game. But with a couple of good mods it's a diamond.

Comment: Yes, the game parts are average. The content is genius and the engine is great, but it takes mods to really make that content shine.

Comment: Sounds cool. So, after I place the two installation files of mod in `\Bethesda Softworks\Oblivion\Data` and `Bethesda Softworks\Oblivion\Data\menus` I simply need to just play the game? Is there anything else I need to do get the mod working?

Comment: @cpx Get the nexus mod manager to load your mods. It is a (mod)launcher for lots of mods hosted by the nexus network. http://www.nexusmods.com/

However some mods need some advanced tool to work. And with all modifications, some are not compatible with eachother. But the nexus mod manager should get you going without problems.

Also get the unofficial patches, they fix a lot.